# JQGrid Column Chooser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the added the following code  after setting the column and other required things in jqGrid

```
.navGrid('#pager', { search: false, view: false, del: false, add: false, edit: false },
       {}, // default settings for edit
       {}, // default settings for add
       {}, // delete instead that del:false we need this
       {closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, // search options
       {} /* view parameters*/
     ).jqGrid ('navButtonAdd', '#pager', { caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator", title: "choose columns",
         onClickButton: function() {
             grid.jqGrid('columnChooser');
         }}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Grid is loading fine. Am trying to implement Column chooser. When i click the button am getting `"Grid is undefined"`. Am i missing any files or is the way that i coded wrong ?

Am stuck here. Correct me if am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you added `$("#grid_name")` before the `.navGrid()` function as specified above?

Comment: Wre i need to add .Can you share

Comment: Try it like this
`$("#grid_name").navGrid('#pager', { search: false, view: false, ...`

Comment: Have added the answer to your question. If problem solved you can accept it

Comment: yes i ll mark it. how do i prevent navbutton added multiple times as many time i click search button

Comment: I think that you should just use `$(this).jqGrid('columnChooser');` instead of `grid.jqGrid('columnChooser');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the gridId before the declaration of your statement so that it can be identified with respect to the grid as given below :

```
$("#grid_name").navGrid('#pager', { search: false, view: false, del: false, add: false, edit: false },
       {}, // default settings for edit
       {}, // default settings for add
       {}, // delete instead that del:false we need this
       {closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, // search options
       {} /* view parameters*/
     ).jqGrid ('navButtonAdd', '#pager', { caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator", title: "choose columns",
         onClickButton: function() {
             grid.jqGrid('columnChooser');
     }}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: Another problem is wenever i click search the navButtonAdd is getting added to the grid multiple times. how to avoid this ?

Comment: I think you are calling the function inside `loadComplete()` or `gridComplete()`. Add the definition of your `navgrid` just outside the definition of your jqGrid. So that it gets called just once. It would be easier if you could share a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your complete code

Comment: I think you could do without the `search: false` parameter and separate the multiplesearch parameters as `{multipleSearch : true},
{closeOnEscape:true}`.

Comment: also change the value of pager from `jquery('#pager')` to `'#pager'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26132/discussion-between-ajo-koshy-and-user2067567)

Comment: I think you should split the definition of `navGrid` as follows : 

`grid.jqGrid ('navGrid', '#pager', 
{edit:false, add:false, del:false, refresh:true, view:false}, 
{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true,overlay:false}); 

grid.jqGrid ('navButtonAdd', '#pager', 
{ 
caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator", title: "choose columns", 
onClickButton: function() { 
grid.jqGrid('columnChooser'); 
} 
});`

Comment: chat is blocked in my network .can u share the changed Fiddle . Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Still issue persists. Thanks for ur tym

Answer (score 0):

Basic mistake.

i was using below code

```
jQuery('#list1').jqGrid
```

but if we want to use grid in other places  we need to use

add at the top

```
  var grid = jQuery('#list1');
```